# React Firebase application - what is the difference between src and public?

Tags: firebase-hosting

I am new to Firebase Hosting, but have quite a lot of experience using ReactJS and android with Firebase. After I created a new project for web, firebase and react created both src folder and public folder.

Is there a reason to have both src and public folders in my project? Can I put the whole project in src and keep only the index.html file in public? Can they "talk" and share data between each other?